# Problemas con SHCreateDefaultContextMenu

Tags: vb.net, shell, visual-studio-2019, x86

El problema es que al querer ejecutar SHCreateDefaultContextMenu marca error (system.accessviolationException) si compilo en x86 y funciona bien si compilo en "AnyCPU"

Este es el código que estoy ejecutando:
Lenguaje: Visual Basic con Visual Studio 2019
Sistema operativo: Windows 10 Home 64 bits
¡Gracias de antemano por su ayuda!

```
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Public Structure DEFCONTEXTMENU
        Public hwnd As IntPtr
        Public pcmcb As IntPtr
        Public pidlFolder As IntPtr
        Public psf As IShellFolder
        Public cidl As UInteger
        Public apidl As IntPtr
        Public punkAssociationInfo As IntPtr
        Public cKeys As UInteger
        Public aKeys As IntPtr
    End Structure

    <DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)>
    Public Function SHCreateDefaultContextMenu(<[In]()> ByVal pdcm As DEFCONTEXTMENU,
                                                    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)> ByVal riid As Guid,
                                                    <Out(), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)> ByRef ppv As Object) As Integer
    End Function

       Sub GetContextMenu(ByVal pidls() As IntPtr)
            Dim _iShellFolder As IShellFolder = Nothing
            _r = SHGetDesktopFolder(_iShellFolder)
            Dim _ObjMnu As Object = Nothing

            Dim DEFcm As DEFCONTEXTMENU = Nothing
            DEFcm.hwnd = ParentWHandle   ' Handle de la ventana del programa llamador
            DEFcm.psf = _iShellFolder    ' iShellFolder obtenido de SHGetDesktopFolder(_iShellFolder)
            DEFcm.cidl = System.Convert.ToInt32(pidls.Length)            ' Longitud de pidls
            DEFcm64.apidl = VarPtr(pidls)                         ' pidls absolutos de archivos que están en diferentes carpetas
            ' Obtiene el iContextMenu de los objetos recibidos
            _r = SHCreateDefaultContextMenu(DEFcm64, IID_IContextMenu, _objmenu)   ' si compilo en "AnyCPU" funciona, pero con "X86" Falla
            If _r = HRESULT.S_OK Then
                ' Lo convierte a IContextMenu
                Me.IContextMenu = TryCast(_ObjMnu, IContextMenu)
            End if
    End Sub
```